# What is industry standard for workflow when training models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm assuming that each time someone trains a model and wants to tweak it/iterate, that they don't have to wait hours and hours for it to learn and then output. So my question is, how do people manage this workflow?

Comment: I cant speak for the industry but for the models I've built  a tweak(generally parameter tuning) means retraining.

Comment: Training takes a long time. You can usually estimate from loss / validation accuracy before you finish a complete training if your ideas work, but it still takes a lot of time. Is this what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

There are online models and there are offline models. Online models make sense when you need to have your model constantly be updated. Otherwise you can save money by updating your model as frequently as necessary; nightly, weekly, etc. The machines used to train models are resources that cost money, after all, and you do not want to reserve them longer than necessary.

One trick to save time is to use the last run's model parameters as initial values for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

After you train a model, you can save the weights that it has learned. Next time when you want to train some more, then you can load those weights and start training from that point again. There is no need to train the model from scratch everytime.